# Everytime I start my MacBook Air there is a blank interface window

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

[image]

When I start my MacBook Air, an empty/blank window appears. Does anybody know how to get rid of or repair it so that when I boot up it doesn´t appear? There is nothing else wrong with it, I can just close the empty window and everything is fine.

Comment: Check your Login items under Preferences -> Users and Groups -> Login Items. You could try removing those you don't need and see if the window appears again next time or not. If you don't need any login items, then remove all and see if it persists.

Comment: Hi Zack, thanks for the response. I tried it and I still have the same problem. I already removed all of the login items. Do you have an idea of what else could it be?

Comment: I remember there is a system utility installed on the mac os that basically works like the "Inspect Elements" from the browser. But I can't find the name and the app now. Anyway, you can take a look at the system logs from "Console" app. You'll have to read through all those lines. I believe it would be there under "system.log" file. To make it easier to read through the log, I would advise you to remove all the login items, and get a big time gap before powering it on. So the time stamp in the log would be easier to differentiate.

Comment: Oh by the way, did the window have it's own icon in the dock?

Comment: Let me try that. And no, it doesn´t have it´s own icon on the dock, it doesnt even appear on the menu bar (let me try to explain it another way, if I click on the window it doenst change that menu bar from the app that I am currently using. For example, if I have Safari open (the menu bar shows Safari on top and its menus) and if I click the blank window, it doesnt change from Safari), does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by reinstalling latest OS. Follow these steps to do it :

1. Shut down your Mac first
2. Restart and keep cmd+R buttons pressed until Apple Logo shown
3. Choose from the menu reinstall OS (in my case : Reinstall Sierra)
4. Follow on screen instructions.

Reinstalling latest OS doesn't change or delete your current settings or installed softwares.

Answer (score 1):

Digging this out as it just happened to me on Mac M1 Monterey : use "UI browser" and activate the screen reader. Hover the mouse on the problematic window and you'll see to which app/process it belongs to... In my case, it was a Vtech app (app to update one of the toys of my kids ...).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/321582)

Comment: I beg to differ. The question was how to get rid of the blank window that pops up upon boot. The solution I propose is to find out which process is causing it (using a free tool) so that one can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using Activity Monitor to tell you which application is opening the window and take it from there. In Activity Monitor.app, select "Windowed Processes" from the drop-down Process filter menu in the app's toolbar. Being as you've just logged in, I doubt you will have many prospects to choose from and the task should be simple enough.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment although it doesnt seem to take care of the problem. If i select Windowed Processes, its only showing the Activity Monitor and Finder... It seems that the Blank Window is not part of any app/program.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with my MPB M2Max (Ventura 13.2). Removing all login items made no difference. Logging into another, pristine account made no difference. Based on the reply from user3360735, I uninstalled the VTech app (Leaning Lodge) from my machine (used for my kid's watch), and the problem was solved. Note: I used the VTech uninstaller app to remove it.